# Error EACCES permission denied mkdir multer node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mkdir, multer

I have a Node.js application server on production running on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, but when I try to connect via browser, the following error shows up on PM2 logs:

```
www-0 (err): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/uploads'
www-0 (err):     at Error (native)
www-0 (err):     at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:794:18)
www-0 (err):     at Function.sync (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/node_modules/multer/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
www-0 (err):     at new DiskStorage (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)
www-0 (err):     at module.exports (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:65:10)
www-0 (err):     at new Multer (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/node_modules/multer/index.js:15:20)
www-0 (err):     at multer (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/node_modules/multer/index.js:88:12)
www-0 (err):     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/app.js:45:9)
www-0 (err):     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
www-0 (err):     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
www-0 (err):     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
www-0 (err):     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
www-0 (err):     at Function._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
www-0 (err):     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
www-0 (err):     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
www-0 (err):     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/bin/www:7:11)
```

As you can see, the error comes from multer package. I am currently using multer version 1.1.0, and this is my `app.js` file:

```
// app.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var multer = require('multer');

var configDB = require('./config/database');

var app = express();

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database
require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
//app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login session
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(multer({ // use multer for processing of multipart/form-data
    dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename){
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file){
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' upload starting...');
    },
    onFileUploadData: function (file, data){
        console.log(data.length + ' of ' + file.fieldname + ' arrived');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file){
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to ' + file.path);
    }
}).single('avatar'));

// routes ======================================================================
require('./routes/routes')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// set production environment
app.set('env', 'production');

// set development environment
//app.set('env', 'development');

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('pages/error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('pages/error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Also, these are the permissions and rights the directories currently have (myuser has sudo privileges)

```
myuser@myhost:~$ ls -dl /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  4 01:17 /var/www

myuser@myhost:~$ ls -dl /var/www/myapp
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Feb  4 01:18 /var/www/myapp

myuser@myhost:~$ ls -dl /var/www/myapp/MyApp
drwxrwxr-x 4 myuser myuser 4096 Feb  4 16:49 /var/www/myapp/MyApp

myuser@myhost:~$ ls -dl /var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp
drwxrwxr-x 12 myuser myuser 4096 Feb  4 16:57 /var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp

myuser@myhost:~$ ls -dl /var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/uploads
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Feb  4 02:04 /var/www/myapp/MyApp/MyApp/uploads
```

By the way, changing to `{ dest: './uploads/'}` gives the same error.

Comment: myuser may have sudo privileges but without using `sudo` to `mkdir` you will get an access denied. And I hope your app does not run with root privileges, thats a recipe for security nightmares.

Comment: @migg how do I make the app use sudo to mkdir? I have no problems when trying it through the command line, it is the app that gets the trouble. Also, I am sure my app does not run with root privileges.

Comment: I think you should not do this, even if it was possible, from a security point of view. The module you are using does not do it. Just change the permissions on the `uploads` folder to writable for the user the app is running on.

Comment: @migg if you can see, the last line shows that myuser does have write permissions on the uploads folder and the app is running on myuser. This is why I don't have a clue on what is going on.

Comment: So then is it correct that the uploads folder already exists, that you are trying to `mkdir`?

Comment: I have tried everything, deleting the directory and then running the app again, but the weird thing is the directory is created again but the error keeps showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102627/discussion-between-migg-and-flizana).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using any IDE for developing Apps then always run that App in sudo mode . 
for eg . If you are using webstorm then always run it's webstorm.sh in file as follows.

> **sudo bash /opt/webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh**

Comment: Not sure this was a suitable answer, would have been better posted as a comment or similar. If you feel it is an answer, please expand more and on how this fixes the OP's issues